# Recover a text file in linux

Tags: linux, file, tar, file-recovery

My project c source code file is corrupted while making the tgz of the file. I wanted to make *.tgz of 4 files. The file names are common.c common.h myfile.c and myfile.h. I mistyped the tar command. I used the following tar command by mistake

`tar -cvf common.* myfile.* project.tgz`

This has corrupted the common.c file. Is there any way to overcome this error?

Comment: Have you tried untarring it with `tar -xvf common.c`?

Comment: I just tried the command which you said. It is not working :(. Any other alternative sir?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I had another idea, but I tried it on my system and it didn't work. I guess if there's anything you learn from this, it's that you should backup everything worth keeping at all times.

Comment: yes .. exactly :(.. Again I should redo the project !! Can there be any other alternative?

Comment: I don't think there is sadly. I don't mean to sound rude, but another thing to consider is that you've already spent 24 minutes looking for a way to recover your missing file, only to be told it's probably not possible. Wouldn't it be a better use of your time to start re-doing it instead of wishing for a miracle and wasting more of your precious time until it's due?

Comment: Yup.. you are right !! Thanks Mister Melancholy !!

Comment: I strongly suggest, for the next project (or if you rewrite this one), to **use some version control system** like [git](http://git-scm.com/) (which is packaged in most linux distributions). It has good [tutorial documentation and videos](http://git-scm.com/documentation)

Comment: BTW, the correct syntax for making a `tar` archive is `tar -czvf project.tgz *.[ch]`  (and if you use a version control system, you won't lose any committed file). With `git` you can make an archive of the project using `git archive`

Comment: Yeah. I know that.. By Mistake I typed it wrongly .. :*

Answer (score 0):

If the file is really important, than umount the related block device, and you can look into it with the strings command. If the file contains something relatively unique, you can grep it, and if you have a little chance you can save the most of the file.
This can work with mounted block devices, but the chance of loosing the data is higher. But it works only under system's where you can access the block device directly.